# Getting smallest subarray that covers all valid entries in a circular array

Tags: arrays

Let's say I have a circular array with some valid and invalid entries i.e.

```
array = [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]
```

I want to find the smallest subarray here that covers all 1s. If this were not a circular array the smallest subarray would be size 10 because it would start with the first 1 and end with the last 1 (inclusive), i.e.

```
[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]
     <----------------->
```

However, as it is a circular array, then I can reduce the subarray size to size `7` i.e.

```
[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]
 -------->           <---
```

My idea is to keep track of 4 pointers i.e. when traversing through the array, the smallest start position would be in `array[2]` because that is the first "1" entry, and the last position would be `array[11]`, therefore the window would be 10. My other two pointers would start in `array[9]` and end in `array[4]`, but how would I know when to stop at `array[4]` and start at `array[9]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're allowing only a single range, consider all adjacent pairs of 1's.

Call their indices `q` and `p`. Each such pair represents the interval from `array[p]` to the end of the array, wrapping around to the start and back to `array[q]`.

It's not hard to see that you want to find such a pair where `p - q` is a *maximum*.  This corresponds to the smallest covering wrap-around interval. Its size is `len(array) - (p - q)`.

The single additional case is the "non-wrapping" one from the leftmost 1 at `q` to rightmost at `p`. This interval has size `p - q`.

All the rest is to arrange the code nicely. Here's one idea:

```py
a = [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]

def find_min_window(arr):
  # Find and remember the leftmost 1
  q0 = p = q = -1
  for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i]:
      q = q0 = i
      break
  # Handle the case of no 1's at all.
  if q == -1:
    return None
  # Find max gap between adjacent pairs of 1's, also the rightmost 1
  max_gap = 0
  a = b = p0 = q0  # Remember rightmost 1 so far.
  while True:
    # Advance p to next 1.
    p = q + 1
    while p < len(arr) and arr[p] == 0:
      p += 1
    # If we scanned off the end of the array, we're done.
    if p == len(arr):
      break
    # Found a 1 at arr[p]. Update rightmost.
    p0 = p 
    # Check the gap
    gap = p - q
    if gap > max_gap:
      (a, b, max_gap) = (p, q, gap)
    # Move on to the next pair.
    q = p
  # Return the non-wrapping case or the wrapping case with largest gap
  return (q0, p0) if p0 - q0 < len(arr) - max_gap else (a, b)

print find_min_window(a)
```

This arrangement has the advantage that it scans the array just once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should do like set a pointer for the first `1` and the last `1` no need for 4 pointers
Start finding first 1 and last one by traversing start (from starting index of array) and  end (from last index) pointers.

The above length obtained would cover the minimum window as for counting all ones you need the last `1` index

```
   start=0; end =0;

       For(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
          If(a[i] =1)
         { start=i;break;}} 
          For(int j=length-1;j>=0;j++)
        {
          If(a[j] =1)
         { last=j;break;}} 

         windowlength=j-i+1;
```

For your above array this would give 
           i=2 and j=11 and windowlength=10

Comment: Thanks but this would be the non-optimal solution, how should I find the wrap around window which would be size 7 and optimal?

Answer (score 0):

Do an initial count of how many 1s should be in the window.

```
N = sum(X)
```

Calculate a new array by concatenating X

```
Y=X+X
```

Use a non circular subset search to find the smallest window with N 1s in Y. Say IX1 is the start of the window and IX2 is the end then the window size is

```
WinSize = IX2 - IX1
```